# How to duplicate a remote session in Terminal?

Tags: terminal

Is it possible to duplicate a remote session in macos terminal?

I want to clone this session without having to connect to the remote host again, so I have two tabs for working expediently.

[image]

Comment: Is there some reason you cannot just open another _tab_ and type the _command_ you want to execute?

Comment: I will re-input password again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each Terminal tab has its own shell and its own connection to a remote server, that can't be easily duplicated.

But you can use a terminal multiplexer like [tmux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmux) for this which will run on the remote server. It will not give you a new Terminal window, but you can switch between virtual terminals inside one window/tab, all within one remote login.

If you are using iterm2 there is [tmux integration](https://iterm2.com/documentation-tmux-integration.html).